# How to estimate a quantity of all matches: str_view and str_subset?

Tags: r, stringr

I want to estimate a quantity of all matches.

str_view (right quantity - 15 in the viewer):

```
    > length(str_view(stringr::fruit, "y$", match = TRUE)) 
      [1] 8
```

str_subset:

```
    > length(str_subset(stringr::fruit, "y$")) 
      [1] 15
```

It is interesting, but when we have no matches - length is again [8]

```
    length(str_view(stringr::fruit, "k$", match = TRUE)) 
    [1] 8
```

Wherefrom is this "8"? And how to use rightly length with str_view?

Comment: Please include your `fruit` dataset.

Comment: `length` returns the length of the vector returned by `str_view`. I think you are looking for `str_count()`?

Comment: @MartinGal this is a preinstalled dataset in the stringr::fruit

Comment: @MartinGal nope, `str_count` counts the number of matches in a string.

Comment: Okay, let's start over: `str_view` isn't the right function to count something. It's purpose is to _show_ the matches and it returns a `list`. So using `length` with `str_view` doesn't return the expected result. Two options are `str_count` and `str_detect` combined with `sum`. Both return `15` with the `"y$"` pattern and `0` with `"k$"`.

Comment: @MartinGal Thanks! It works! I'm a stupid head. Dont know why i have wanted to count with `str_view`